# Was trying to include GLUT in my openGL project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm using VS2010 and whilst I was trying to include GLUT so that I could attempt to get the deltaTime I included all of the .libs .dll and the .h into the corresponding files as well as creating the appropriate property sheet and linking everything up. After doing so when I tried to run my project I now get LNK 1181: cannot open input file 'obccp32.lib'. Obviously my first thought was to undo all of the changes that I had done whilst trying to include GLUT into my project.

However this seems to have made no difference to the issue and I'm still stuck with the linker error. Any help is appreciated.

VS2010 proffessional 64 bit on Windows 7. (Just to include that info)

Comment: Why do you think that this is realted to GLUT or OpenGL at all?  You seem to have added `obccp32.lib` to your linker inputs. Not even google does know what that is, but it is certainly not related to glut or opengl.

Comment: Speedutilities suggests that `obccp32.lib` is a typo of `ODBCCP32.lib`, which has a lot more hits. Either way, most likely nothing to do with OpenGL or GLUT

Comment: Because I didn't add any other libraries other than GLUT. And I already had the base OpenGL stuff in my project? So common sense says that something happened whilst installing GLUT?

Comment: Yeah... I fixed it... How the hell that happened I have no clue >.>

Answer (score 0):

Some how odbccp.lib dependancys name got changed. (no clue since I didn't touch anywhere near that library in my linker properties) But oh well. Thanks to derhass and Colonel Thirty Two for helping me realise what the issue was.